# Palabra para designar al juego de cambiar las vocales de palabras

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Mi hijo está empezando a divertirse con el lenguaje. Ahora le ha dado por cambiar las vocales de algunas palabras, de modo que le hace gracia cómo suenan. La última ha sido decir "Papá Noól".

El caso es que me recuerda a esas canciones que consisten en cantar un estribillo, como "tengo una hormiguita en la patita" y luego repetir la frase usando siempre la misma vocal: "tanga ana harmagata an la patata". Recuerdo que de pequeño nos reíamos mucho con esa canción.

Mi pregunta es: ¿existe alguna palabra para designar al hecho de cambiar las vocales de una palabra por diversión? Bueno, por diversión, por forzar una rima graciosa, o lo que sea. Puede que exista alguna figura poética similar, o algo así. Pensaba en palabras como [retruécano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WLgrFgS), que designan un tipo de juego con las palabras.

Comment: ¿[Paranomasia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RxwYjrb)? No del todo pero [lo mencionan](http://www.juegosdepalabras.com/parono.htm) como juego.

Comment: @fedorqui se parece, pero no. En todo caso, una palabra así estoy buscando, si es que existe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dudo que exista un nombre específico para designar ese juego, pero -- genéricamente hablando -- se trata de un juego de palabras que inclusive se aproximaría a un trabalenguas por la tendencia normal del hablante a utilizar las vocales que corresponden y no las que se ve forzado a usar (allí radica, justamente, la dificultad del juego).

El juego se basa en la ALITERACIÓN VOCÁLICA artificial o forzada, en contraste con la ALITERACIÓN VOCÁLICA como recurso o figura literaria, propia de palabras correctamente dichas como: Amaba la mar salada.

A propósito, deseo compartir un recuerdo de mi infancia, cuando era muy común ese juego que consistía en convertir palabras con diversas vocales en palabras monovocálicas. Entonces entonábamos una canción que decía: La mar estaba serena, serena estaba la mar, la mar estaba serena, serena estaba la mar.

Con A: La mar astaba sarana, sarana astaba la mar, ...

Y así sucesivamente. De más está decir que la "U" era la vocal que, por su realización fonética, más divertida y complicada resultaba: Lu mur ustubu surunu, surunu ustubu lu mur, ...

Answer (score 1):

Pues sí, en mi país también se hace eso. Bueno, lo hacíamos más las generaciones anteriores, éstas ya no mucho. De hecho, hay una canción en mi país que es de alguien famoso para mi país, Aniceto Molina, que usa ese lenguaje. Pues me puse a buscar porque me interesó tu pregunta y no sé si estoy mal, pero me suena algo a esto:

[Palabras Monovocalicas](http://www.juegosdepalabras.com/vocales/monovocal.html)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el país?

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Lo que comentas de las palabras monovocálicas son palabras que de por sí se construyen con una única vocal, como "excelentemente". No es exactamente lo que preguntaba, pero te agradezco igualmente la intención.

Comment: Aniceto Molina es colombiano, así que... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯